# image display in IE 7

Tags: css

I have a page like [http://ratingscorner.com/mobiles](http://abc.com/mobiles)

if u see the left hand side there is a + image displayed. it does not appear in IE 7. i tried all possible things ..but could not solve it. so seeking help here.. any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly state the width and height in your css declaration for `.plus`

```
span.plus {
   width:12px;
   height:12px;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean 'explicitly state' ... he's already implying the height and width by not defining them.

Answer (score 1):

It is a span, inline element.

Add `display: block;` and specify the height and width.

Also it behaves the same in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has a height and width of 0, so it won't show up in IE7 at all.  I did some quick debugging and found that if you set the height to 15px and display to block, then it shows up just fine.  Adding a left float helped move it to the left of the button name.

So to your `.Syb .plus` CSS definition, add:

```
height:15px;
display:block;
float:left;
```

Then you should be fine.